# RegEx for filtering in Azure using Terraform

Tags: regex, azure, terraform, virtual-machine, azure-rm

The Terraform `azurerm_image` data source lets you use a RegEx to identify a machine image whose ID matches the regular expression.

> ***What RegEx should be used to retrieve an image that includes the string `MyImageName` and that takes the complete form `/subscriptions/abc-123-def-456-ghi-789-jkl/resourceGroups/MyResourceGroupName/providers/Microsoft.Compute/images/MyImageName1618954096`  ?***

The following version of the RegEx is throwing an error because it will not accept two `*` characters.  However, when we only used the trailing `*`, the image was not retrieved.

```
data "azurerm_image" "search" {
  name_regex          = "*MyImageName*"
  resource_group_name = var.resourceGroupName
}
```

Note that the results only return a single image so you do not need to worry about multiple images being returned.  There is a flag that can be set to specify either ascending or descending sorting to retrieve the oldest or the newest match.

The precise error we are getting is:

```
Error: "name_regex": error parsing regexp: missing argument to repetition operator: `*`
```

***Nick's Suggestion***

Per @Nick's suggestion, we tried:

```
data "azurerm_image" "search" {
  name_regex          = "/MyImageName[^/]+$"
  resource_group_name = 
var.resourceGroupName
}
```

But the result is:

```
Error: No Images were found for Resource Group "MyResourceGroupName"
```

We checked in the Azure Portal and there is an image that includes `MyImageName` in its name within the resource group named `MyResourceGroupName`.  We also confirmed that Terraform is running as the subscription owner, so we imagine that the subscription owner has sufficient authorization to filter image names.

What else can we try?

Comment: `*` means repeat the previous character 0 or more times. In your "regex", you have no character prior to the first `*`, hence the error. Your second regex doesn't work because it matches the string `MyImageNam` followed by 0 or more `e`s. You probably want something like `/MyImageName[^/]+$`

Comment: @Nick  Thank you.  We just posted the results of trying your suggestion to the end of the OP.  Any further ideas?

Comment: If the regex needs to match the *entire* name, then perhaps `.+/MyImageName[^/]+`? Unfortunately I can't see any docs on this parameter to give any more clues. btw have you tried putting in the exact name (as a `name` rather than a `name_regex`) to check that that matches?

Comment: @Nick Thank you again.  The change you suggested results in the same error.  And then when we pasted the actual image's entire resource id that we manually copied from the Azure portal explicitly inside double quotes `"..."`, we also got the same error.

Comment: Sorry, then, this is beyond my level of knowledge of terraform (which is to say, none :). The regex I have given you should match the name string (see for example https://regex101.com/r/mhNhVi/1). I hope you can find someone else with more expertise in terraform to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After my validation, it seems that it works when `name_regex` includes only one trailing `*`. If with one prefix `*`, it will generate that error message.

For example, I have an image name `rrr-image-20210421150018` in my resource group.

The following works:

```
r*
-*
8*
rrr*
image*
2021*
```

The following does not work:

```
*r
*-
*8
*image*
*rrr*
```

Also, verify if you have the latest azurerm provider.

**Result**

[image]

Comment: Our problem was downstream.  Your response here helped us refocus our attention on downstream potential causes, which led to a resolution of our actual problem which is out of scope for this OP.  Thank you and +1.